# How to detect variable dependencies for a javascript function

Tags: javascript, compilation

Say I have this function:

```
function test(){
    return a + b + 1;
}
```

How can I dynamically figure out that it will require globals a and b to be able to run? E.g. something like `get_dependencies(test)` returns `['a', 'b']`

Comment: FWIW, `a` and `b` don't have to be *globals*, they just have to be defined in the containing scope (which may not be the global scope).

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do that in standard JavaScript, if you're trying to do it with JavaScript itself.

On nearly all (but not all) JavaScript engines, you can get a form of the source of a function from the function object's `toString` function, e.g.:

```
var testSource = test.toString();
```

...and then of course you could parse that. This is non-standard behavior (the result of calling `toString` on a function is [not defined in the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.2)), but it's widely-supported. You'd still have to do the parsing to find the symbols.

For the parsing, you have a couple of options. You could try to separate the parser portion of [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) out of the rest of it, or alternately the terribly-named [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) compressor has a full JavaScript parser which is already separate from the compressor part (see parse-js.js; apparently there's a tiny bit of NodeJS-specific stuff you might want to remove).

Comment: Thanks @T.J. I might give this a try - I'm guessing there's a regex that's not *too* complicated that would cover 90% of cases which is good enough for me for now.

Comment: @Trindaz: Re the regex: Probably not. Consider the complexity of comments (both styles of them), string literals (both styles of them), regular expression literals, etc. A simple regex giving you, for instance, all of the identifier-like things would be blown up by those. Still, with some pre-processing you could probably do a 90% solution...

Comment: @Trindaz: Added some notes to the answer on parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Javascript 'lint' tool that will test your code for common mistakes or oddities.

Some can be found online:

- http://www.jslint.com/
- http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php (can also be downloaded)

In your case, you might want to isolate individual functions via a regular expression for example, and submit them to such a tool.